# VBA code to auto serial number in column A when data entered in the userform

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have a userform in which user can fill the data and data will insert in column C to Z. I need a code, either in worksheet or in userform to auto fill serial number starting with `BA00860` which will fill in column A everytime data has enter.

I tried with the below Code under the `Commandbutton_Click` I was able to generate Serial numbers from `BA00860` to `BA00869`, then after it is starting with `BA01861` but not `BA00870`.  Please correct my code as I required to be `BA00860` … `BA00870` … `BA00880` and so on.

```
Me.txtId.Value = "BA" & Format(Application.Max(Sheets("Tasks").Range("A12:A65536")) + 1, "00860")

ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0).Value = Me.txtId.Value

ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0).NumberFormat = "00860"
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that this `.NumberFormat = "00860"` is no valid number format.

You can do this easily with a formula. Assume your first serial number is written in A1 like …

[image]

Then you can just use the formula `=LEFT(A1,2) & TEXT(RIGHT(A1,5)+1,"00000")` in cell A2 and copy it down to get the following:

[image]

In VBA you could use something like

```
Dim LastSN As String
LastSN = Range("A1").Value 'eg BA00860

Dim NextSN As String
NextSN = Left$(LastSN, 2) & Format$(Right(LastSN, 5) + 1, "00000")
```

Full example according comments:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim LastSN As String
    LastSN = "BA00860"

    Dim NextSN As String
    NextSN = Left$(LastSN, 2) & Format$(Right(LastSN, 5) + 1, "00000")

    MsgBox "LastSN was: " & LastSN & vbCrLf & "NextSN is: " & NextSN
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes I understood using formula but for my requirement it should generate from userform.

Comment: I am trying with your edited Code, but where I shall include "BA"

Comment: Little confused, from where the code will take " Left$(LastSN, 2) as BA " becasue I am not defining anywhere in the Excel

Comment: Me.txtId.Value = "BA" & Format(Application.Max(Sheets("Tasks").Range("A12:A65536")) + 1, "00860 ==> in this line I am Clearing indicating to start with "BA"

Comment: but this is using the last serial number `LastSN` which could be something like `BA00860` extracts `BA` from it, extracts `00860` from it and adds `+1` which results in `861` and formats them back to 5 digits `00861` and puts all together to `BA00861`. You just need to put the last serial number to which you want to add `+1` into `LastSN` and it will work.

Comment: 00861
00862
00863
00864
00865
00866
00867
00868
00869
01860
I am getting values like this and without "BA"

Comment: What did you input as `LastSN`? It should be something like `BA00860` as I told you in my example, then it will work. If you do something different then it does not work of course.

Comment: Yes I have given exacetly as you mentioned but also i am not able detect "BA" and the Serial number after 00869 is 01860 instead of 00870

Comment: I added a full example (see edit) to proof that this works as intended. I don't know what but you must be doing something wrong.

Comment: @Santo I cannot tell, I don't know what you are doing, to less information. You need to put in some effort yourself now. My example works and clearly shows how to increase the serial number. I cannot give you a code that you just need to copy/paste, sorry. Therefore your question is a way too broad.

Comment: Can I use this Code for adding up values "Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A" & A65536 & ":A" & A65536 + 1), Type:=xlFillDefault "